# Does react have a hook for listening for interactions on multiple inputs and updating that inputs relevant state using a setFoo( ) method

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, event-handling, dom-events

Is there a way to set multiple pieces of state with one event listener function.
I am trying to get information from the user that will update in real time other sections of my app. I am using the const `[state, setState ] = useState()` method.

I would like each input to fire a function off that will update the relevant parts of state but I can't work out how to do it.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { Container } from 'react-bootstrap'

const HBB = () => {

const [planName ,setPlanName ] = useState('')
const [planType ,setPlanType ] = useState('')
const [HBBInstallation ,setHBBInstallation ] = useState(false)
const [HBBInstallationActivationDate, setHBBInstallationActivationDate ] = useState()
const [HBBInstallationSlot , setHBBInstallationSlot ] = useState()
const [planOptions, setPlanOptions] = useState()
const [planMonthlyCost, setPlanMonthlyCost] = useState(0)


const handleChange = (e) => {
    let proToUpdate = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    let test = e.target.id;
 //set the state of the element eg setPlanName(value)
 
    
}
return (
    <Container>
    <div>
        <div className="form-group">
            <select name="planName" id="setPlanName" value={planName} className="plan w-40" onChange={handleChange}>
                <option value="*">Plan</option>
                <option value="TEST">TEST</option>
        </select>
        <select name="planType" className="plan w-40" value={planType} onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value="*">Standard</option>
            <option value="pro">Pro</option>
            <option value="extra">Extra</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="No">No Installation Needed</label>
        <input name="HBBinstallation" id="No" type="radio" className="plan" value="No" checked onChange={handleChange}/>
        <label htmlFor="Yes">Installation needed</label>    
        <input name="HBBinstallation" type="radio" className="plan" value="Yes"/>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <input name="HBBInstallationActivationDate" type="text" className="textInput plan" value={HBBInstallationActivationDate} placeholder="Installation/Activation date" onChange={handleChange}/>
        <select name="HBBinstallationSlot" className="plan">
            <option value="*" defaultValue>Choose slot--</option>
            <option value="am">AM</option>
            <option value="pm">PM</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div className="form-group">
        <input name="planMonthlyCost" type="number" className="plan" value={planMonthlyCost} placeholder="Plan Monthly Cost" onChange={handleChange}/>
        </div>
</div>
</Container>
)
 }

export default HBB
```

Is it possible to pass the `setState` method through the `onChange` attr?
Will I need to write a function for each `setState` inputs?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `useReducer` hook, you can handle multiple state easily like below code.

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

const useReducerState = (initialState = {}) => {
  const reducer = (prev, next) => ({ ...prev, ...next });
  return useReducer(reducer, initialState);
};
const HBB = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useReducerState({
    planName: "",
    planType: "",
    HBBInstallationActivationDate: 0,
    HBBInstallation: false,
    HBBInstallationSlot: [],
    planOptions: [],
    planMonthlyCost: 0
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    let proToUpdate = e.target.name;
    let value = e.target.value;
    let test = e.target.id;
    setState({ [proToUpdate]: value });
  };


  const {
    planName,
    planType,
    HBBInstallationActivationDate,
    HBBInstallation,
    HBBInstallationSlot,
    planOptions,
    planMonthlyCost
  } = state;
  return (
    <Container>
      <div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <select
            name="planName"
            id="setPlanName"
            value={planName}
            className="plan w-40"
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <option value="*">Plan</option>
            <option value="TEST">TEST</option>
          </select>
          <select
            name="planType"
            className="plan w-40"
            value={planType}
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            <option value="*">Standard</option>
            <option value="pro">Pro</option>
            <option value="extra">Extra</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="No">No Installation Needed</label>
          <input
            name="HBBinstallation"
            id="No"
            type="radio"
            className="plan"
            value="No"
            checked
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="Yes">Installation needed</label>
          <input
            name="HBBinstallation"
            type="radio"
            className="plan"
            value="Yes"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            name="HBBInstallationActivationDate"
            type="text"
            className="textInput plan"
            value={HBBInstallationActivationDate}
            placeholder="Installation/Activation date"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <select name="HBBinstallationSlot" className="plan">
            <option value="*" defaultValue>
              Choose slot--
            </option>
            <option value="am">AM</option>
            <option value="pm">PM</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <input
            name="planMonthlyCost"
            type="number"
            className="plan"
            value={planMonthlyCost}
            placeholder="Plan Monthly Cost"
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default HBB;
```

Then, you can use setState function for changing all the state values.
For using this method, you always have to set the initial value for the state.

Comment: thanks so much. I don't really understand it but it works and seems like a good thing to learn. Thanks for your help

Comment: thanks for the above. Do you know how I would get this working for the radio buttons. Everything else is working great but I can't get the radios to update

Comment: NVM I realised the issue